# How would I split up a small black of text into Arraylists in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, bufferedreader, reader

I need to parse a .txt file into java and split it up into Arraylists based on columns. How would I actually go about getting the data into the lists?

The .txt file looks something like this

```
1 A 9 Z
2 B 8 X
1 B 9 X
2 A 9 Z
```

And I want to create 4 array lists that would be like this:

```
Array List 1: < 1, 2, 1, 2>
Array List 2: < A, B, B, A>
Array List 3: < 9, 8, 9, 9>
Array List 4: < Z, X, X, Z>
```

This is what i've already tried:

```
BufferedReader FSMreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));      
        List<FSMline> line = new ArrayList<>(); 
        List<String> currentState = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> inputChoice = new ArrayList<>(); 
        List<String> outputFunction = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> nextState = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then i tried comma splitting it:

```
 while ((lines = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            line.add(new FSMline(lines.split(",")));
```

but its not going well and i don't know where to go from here or if i should use a for or a while loop

I'm just very stuck :/

Comment: Why are you comma splitting? I don't see any commas in your file.

Comment: @Kayaman i thought it might make it easer to put into the array list. i'm just very confused on what to do

Comment: Well, do you understand why comma splitting doesn't work?

Comment: You're right in thinking that `split` will make things easier for you.  But, as @Kayaman is ever-so-subtly pointing out,  your file uses _blanks_ to separate the data, not commas. 
So doesn't `lines.split(" ")` make more sense?

Comment: @KevinAnderson ill try that,

Comment: @Kayaman i do now haha. I'll give this another shot

Answer (score 1):

You should try filling up an array of rows first and then transpose to get it in column-major form. I would do something like this:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(/* other stuff here*/);

ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while((line = r.readLine()) != null)
    rows.add(line.split(" "));

ArrayList<String> currentState = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> inputChoice = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> outputFunction = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> nextState = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++){
    currentState.add(rows.get(i)[0]);
    inputChoise.add(rows.get(i)[1]);
    outputFunction.add(rows.get(i)[2]);
    nextState.add(rows.get(i)[3]);
}
```

Of course these steps can be combined but I'm just trying to show you how it works

Comment: do the names i1, i2, o1, and o2 represent anything? thanks

Comment: They represent the four lists you mentioned in your question. I mislabeled them a bit sorry. Editing now